# Python adding spaces between letters and * to end of word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a text file and have it output like this.

```
(h i * m y * n a m e * i s * b o b *)
```

it is currently outputting with the asterisk at the end

[image: Here is a pic]

Comment: How is the content inside the file ? One line, many lines ?

Comment: Please [do not post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10077).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `str.join` and `str.split`:

```
data = "hi my name is bob"
print(' '.join('*'.join(data.split())))
```

---

```
h i * m y * n a m e * i s * b o b
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- split lines in words to join them with `' * '`
- split words in letters to join them with `' '`

```
with open("file123.txt") as fic:
    for line in fic:
        x = ' * '.join(" ".join(w) for w in line.split())
        print('(' + x + ')')

# input file
Hi my name is Bob
Hi this is Foo

# output console
(H i * m y * n a m e * i s * B o b)
(H i * t h i s * i s * F o o)
```

Comment: No need to turn str to list, a str is an iterable